# Trying to create composite unique index with partialFilterExpression

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I'm trying to create an unique index for my collection with composite keys, but some documents might have null on the fields of the index. Going by the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraints) it seems I should be able to do it with *partialFilterExpression*.

I tried it as following:

```
db.collection.createIndex( 
 { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 },
 { 
   "background":true, 
   "unique": true, 
   "partialFilterExpression": { 
     "a": { "$exists": true }, 
     "b": { "$exists": true }, 
     "c": { "$exists": true } 
   } 
 })
```

but that gave me the following error:

> exception: E11000 duplicate key error collection: schema.collection index: a_1_b_1_c_1 dup key: { : null, : null, : null }

I even tried changing the partial filter criteria to this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
  { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 },
  { 
    "background":true,
    "unique": true,
    "partialFilterExpression": { 
      "a": { "$exists": true, "$ne": null  },
      "b": { "$exists": true, "$ne": null  },
      "c": { "$exists": true, "$ne": null  }
    } 
  }
)
```

But still returned the same error.

Did I misunderstand the use or am using it wrongly?

Comment: Furthermore you are trying to *'re-invent the wheel"*. MongoDB has a ["sparse indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) option, which does what you want already `db.collection.createIndex({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 },{ "background": true, "unique": true, "sparse": true })`. Though as noted in the documentation you can "do more" with the newer option, the default behavior fits this specific case.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't suit my case. I have some documents in which *a* is present, but *b* or *c* aren't. In that case when I try to create the sparse index it fails with duplicate index `{a: something, b: null, c: null}`. That's why I went for that specific feature, because I needed the validation only when all three were present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what was my issue. The version of my monogo is 3.0.12 and *partialFilterExpression* was introduced in version 3.2

Comment: i am using mongodb version 3.0.12  how i can achieve the behaviour of partialFilterExpression. is there any solution?